# Ruby I/O internal buffer size

Tags: ruby, io

I know that Ruby has its own internal buffer which is used when writing to files. When writing to a file, the data is not passed to the OS (let alone the disk) immediately, but first it's written into the in-memory buffer. By calling `IO#flush` or closing the file, this buffer can be flushed to the OS.

My question is how do I find out what the maximum size of this buffer is, i.e. how big does Ruby allow it to get before it's invariably flushed, even without using `flush` or `fsync`?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby uses the same underlying mechanism to store strings as it does to store IO buffers. Good evidence of that is that IO#write takes a String instance for its buffer if you want to provide one!

Ruby strings are limited only by available memory. Therefore, IO buffers are limited by available memory. And of course in most systems, available memory includes swap space on disk, so Ruby strings can get very large (and very slow).

Ruby does not just flush when the buffer "fills up" - it dumps the buffer more frequently than that, but I do not know the precise algorithm it uses.

To get a definitive answer on when precisely Ruby decides to flush the buffer, you're going to have to read the Ruby io.c source (I'd start at line 665 of this file https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/io.c). My experience in the past trying to read the Ruby C source hasn't been a ton of fun.